# WooCommerce membership directory restrictions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

I have a WordPress members site using WooCommerce and WooCommerce membership plugins.

We have a members page that is restricted to signed up paid members and gives them access to a TV channel.

The problem we have is that a member can gain access to the page, copy the HTML and view the TV channel without membership.

As it's the videos and images we want to stop hotlinking to I was wondering if the following may work.

1. Each member has a membership number (WordPress database id), could we scramble that id and add it to the TV channel URL. This will allow us to descramble the id, check if that user has a current membership, and if they do allow access.
2. At this point where we know the WordPress database id is granted access we need a way to show the TV channel without revealing the real TV channel URL.

Is this at all possible and would anyone have any suggestions on how this could be put together?

I'm also open to other solutions if you have them.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just simply run a conditional on the page to check if a user has membership, and output the secure content inside of the conditional? Your else condition can display a 'Sorry, you need membership' message, or even direct to another page if you want.

Comment: Hi there, That's exactly how it works right now but people can hotlink the TV channel outside of the site and membership restrictions.

Comment: You can't hotlink code within a PHP conditional; they would only be able to view the source of the page. If you only **output** that HTML inside of a PHP condition for membership, when a bot / scraper tries to view the page, they won't see it, as they won't be logged in as a member. Only valid members would be able to see the content. See [this simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3812555/2341603).

Comment: I understand but we have members that cancel once they have the hotlinks. And they then access to the TV feed. I'll try what you suggest as I may be missing something quite simple.