# How can I make changes/modify HTML code by using PHP code

Tags: php, html, authentication, phpstorm

[image: Block of code that demonstrate the header.php]

This is common and I have been googling for hours but found not many helpful answers. How would I get rid of the sign up button after user has been logged in? can we modify or chanage things outside of the php block of code?

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Put an `if` statement around the code that displays the sign up button.

Comment: Who do both the login and signup buttons both link to the same `register.php` script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Statements in PHP code Between HTML Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812526/conditional-statements-in-php-code-between-html-code)

Comment: Barmar, we have Jquery run hide and show methods for the login form and register form respectively so you don't have to create each page for each form, maybe  this is not the best way to build a website but it works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
if(!$logged_in)
{ 
   echo "<li><a href='register.php'>Sign up!</a></li>"; 
}  
?>
```

Change if condition based on your authentication code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another php code block around the button, and render the button conditionally. That would then execute on the server, which is likely the best.

Alternatively, client-side code can be written to achieve the same (javascript), but it would likely be more complex for you (it would potentially involve an ajax request and some js code, depending on how you deliver the rest of the page.content.